# An error occurred when using binding in C#

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml, binding

```
<ListView Margin="6,6,5,7" x:Name="lvBB" Foreground="Black" >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="10" Background="{Binding SelectedNotamColor}">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Priority}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>                            
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SelectedNotamColor, mode=Toway}"/>
   </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>              
</ListView>
```

I am binding a json object which has the property called `SelectedNotamColor`, if I use it in the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` setter, when I try to save my json object into a text file it will occur an error like this

> System.InvalidOperationException：the object is being used

and when I delete the setter property, it will come back to normal.

How to solve this problem or is there any other way to bind my `ListView` items' color?

Comment: Try changing your BindingMode from `mode=TwoWay` to `mode=Oneway`. This may resolve the error, but I do not know OneWay binding logic suits you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have syntax error in your style setter property.
   Try to replace
   `mode=Towway`
   with 
   `mode=TwoWay`
2. I coudn't find line of code where you fill items of your listbox. 
   For example, in XAML:
   `ItemsSource="{Binding YourListOfJsonObjects}` 
   or code behind: 
   `lvBB.ItemsSource = YourListOfJsonObjects`

Comment: can you put here or anywhere relative pieces of source code?

Comment: I resolved this error by change the {Binding SelectedNotamColor}, formerly, SelectedNotamColor was a Brush but it may cause UI thread error. So I change it into string then it works all fine.  Thanks.